# Method which will find record in sql database by given by user value

Tags: android, sql, database

I need to make a method who will fill TextView with data from database by using "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID = getID. For example we have one record in database which id is equals to "1" now,we can enter "1" in EditText,then we have to click on get data button,then program should display data from database where column id is equals to "1"

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper db;
EditText name, surname, marks, enterID;
Button addData, showData,queryButton;
TextView testTV;
String idString,nameString,surnameString,marksString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameET);
    surname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.surnameET);
    marks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.marksET);
    enterID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterIdET);

    addData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addDataBtn);
    showData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showDataBtn);
    queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testBTN);

    testTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showID);




    AddData();
    showData();
    queryTest();
}
public void queryTest() {
    queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String givenID = enterID.getText().toString();
            Cursor cursor = db.Test(Integer.parseInt(enterID.getText().toString()));


            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    idString = "ID :" + cursor.getString(0);
                    nameString = "Name :" + cursor.getString(1);
                    surnameString = "Surname :" + cursor.getString(2);
                    marksString = "Marks :" + cursor.getString(3);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                {
                    testTV.setText(idString + "\n" + nameString + "\n" + surnameString + "\n" + marksString);
                }
            }


        }
    });
}
public void AddData() {
    addData.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = db.insertData(name.getText().toString(),
                            surname.getText().toString(),
                            marks.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}

public void showData() {
    showData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Cursor res = db.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                showMessage("Error", "No data");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext()) {

                buffer.append("ID :" + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Name :" + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Surname :" + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Marks :" + res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
            }
            showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
        }
    });
}


public void showMessage(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
}
```

DatabaseHelper (the method that i want to create has name "Test" for now)

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "asd.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_2+" TEXT,"+COL_3+" TEXT,"+COL_4+" INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String marks) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,marks);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    }else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllData(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor Test(int getID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_2+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE ID ="+getID+"''",null);
    return cursor;
}
}
```

For now,when i'll click on get data button,i'll received communicate Database (Database is my app name) has stopped

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can see mine methods in edited question.

Comment: In your Test() method you retrieved only one column but in queryTest() method you tried to get 4 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
"SELECT "+COL_2+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE ID ="+getID+"''"
```

must be replaced with:

```
"SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE ID ="+getID
```

Comment: I've changed this line,and i've received "Database has stopped"

Comment: You mean "app has stopped"? Post the logcat.

Comment: Yes,it's just a dummy name of app. :) here's the logs,i hope i posted the right one                            [link to logs](http://www.wklejto.pl/609005)

Comment: Do you mean that the previous line you had did not crash the app?

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much sir. I never have luck to this sql syntax.. :) Previous version of syntax crashes app too,but it finally works.. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the entirety of your code? If so, it seems as though you haven't added any data to it, which would cause issues with accessing data.

Also, your query in the Test(String ID) method doesn't have any spaces. Essentially, the query you're sending is like this:

SELECTCOLUMNFROMTABLEWHERE ID =7

whereas it should be like this:

SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 7;

Hopefully this helps, good luck with your code!

Comment: Of course i've added data. I will edit the question,and add all 
 of my code.